# Find branches in Plastic "Branch Explorer"

Tags: regex, plasticscm

Is it possible to specify in BranchExplorer's search box that I do not want to select "subbranches", but the branch with a given name?

For example I have a branch `/main/ver1/` and many subranches `/main/ver1/task001`, `/main/ver1/task002`, ...

When I put either `/main/ver1` or `/main/ver1/` into search box, it jumps over all subranches `task001`, `task002`(Which is not useful when I want to diff the latest changeset of branch `/main/ver1/task122` with the latest changeset of `ver1` base branch or switch workspace to base branch)

[image: search box]

In words of regex expressions, I want to see `.*/ver1[^/]` branch.

Answer (score 1):

- From the Branches view:
  In that case, click on the "Advanced" button and you will be able to configure your custom queries:

eg:

```
find branch where name like '%ver1' 

find branch where name='task122'
```

You will find more examples in our "cm find" guide:

http://plasticscm.com/documentation/cmfind/plastic-scm-version-control-query-system-guide.shtml

- From the Branch Explorer view:

You can drive to "Filters and conditional format", and enter your custom query

eg: (not including "cm find")

```
name like '%ver1'
name='task122'
```

You can play with inclusion, exclusion and format rules.

PD: You can perform diff, update... from both views

Comment: Where do you see "Advanced" button in BranchExplorer?

Comment: I´ve edited the answer to explain how to filter branches in both views: "Branches" and "Branch Explorer".